# Allow beta testers to test google play billing, but only for one app?

Tags: android, google-play-console, beta-testing

I have followed the instructions here 
https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing#testing-purchases
in order to allow beta testers to make test in-app purchase (without actually paying).

Yet, there is a big flaw: there is no way to mention that the testing should only apply to the beta-tested app, is there?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

These accounts are usually not for public beta testers. They are for helping internal testing while you are developing the payment part of your app.

This feature is for testing while you are doing app development, and not designed to let all your beta testers get free stuff.

Comment: Well, does it mean that I should hard code some booleans to cancel in-apps for the time of the beta test? Because I would like them to test features that are supposed to be only accessible for premium users. But then, if I do this, they will also have the option to never install the final release, just to keep the free stuff with the boolean on (or I guess I could use Firebase to turn it off later...).

Comment: Normally app developers want beta testers to give some them information about how appealing the paid for products are - if none of your beta testers want to buy them, then probably none of your production users will either. And experimenting with monetization and prices before launch is very important. But yes, you could always use firebase remote config